# Vue 3 components not awaiting for state to be loaded

Tags: async-await, vuex, vuejs3

I am having some trouble using fetch in vuex to build state before rendering my page's components.

Here is the page component code:

```
  async beforeCreate() {
    await this.$store.dispatch('projects/getProjects');
  },
```

And this is the state code it's dispatching:

```
  async getProjects(context: any, parms: any) {
      context.commit("loadingStatus", true, { root: true });

      console.log("1");
      await fetch(`${process.env.VUE_APP_API}/projects?`, {
        method: "get",
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
        },
      })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log("2");
          if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(response.status.toString());
          } else {
            return response.json();
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // todo: tratamento de erros na UI
          console.error("There was an error!", error);
        })
        .then((data) => {
          context.commit("setProjects", { data });
          console.log("3");
          // sets the active project based on local storage
          if (
            localStorage.getItem(
              `activeProjectId_${context.rootState.auth.operator.accountId}`
            )
          ) {
            console.log("setting project to storage");
            context.dispatch("selectProject", {
              projectId: localStorage.getItem(
                `activeProjectId_${context.rootState.auth.operator.accountId}`
              ),
            });
          } else {
            //or based on the first item in the list
            console.log("setting project to default");
            if (data.length > 0) {
              context.dispatch("selectProject", {
                projectId: data[0].id,
              });
            }
          }

          context.commit("loadingStatus", false, { root: true });
        });
    },
    async selectProject(context: any, parms: any) {
      console.log("4");
      context.commit("loadingStatus", true, { root: true });
      const pjt = context.state.projects.filter(
        (project: any) => project.id === parms.projectId
      );

      if (pjt.length > 0) {
        console.log("Project found");
        await context.commit("setActiveProject", pjt[0]);
      } else if (context.state.projects.length > 0) {
        console.log("Project not found setting first on the list");
        await context.commit("setActiveProject", context.state.projects[0]);
      } else {
        await context.commit("resetActiveProject");
      }
      await context.commit("loadingStatus", false, { root: true });
    },
```

I've added this console.log (1, 2, 3, 4) to help me debug what's going on.
Right after console.logging "1", it starts to mount the components. And I only get logs 2, 3 and 4 after all components have been loaded.

How can I make it so that my components will only load after the whole process is done (i.e. after I log "4") ?

Answer (score 0):

If your `beforeCreate` hook (or any client hooks) contains async code, Vue will NOT wait to it then render and mount the component.

The right choice here should be showing a loader when your data is fetching from the server. It will provide better UX:

```html
<template>
  <div v-if="!data"> Loading... </div>
  <div v-else> Put all your logic with data here </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        data: null
      }
    },
    async beforeCreate() {
       this.data = await this.$store.dispatch('projects/getProjects');
    },
  }
</script>
```

Comment: UX not the problem.. problem is that the child components require the data that I am pulling from the store. If they load before that data is retrieved, they'll fail to function.

Comment: The components use a method to check user permissions to decide whether to show some components. But the user permission check function requires on the data from the store to run.

Comment: @LuisNovo I forgot the `v-else` in my answer. Updated. You simply just need to put your child component inside that `v-else` to make it function correctly